# What is the best way to check whether a string is all upper-case in JavaScript:

Tags: javascript

I have searched it for a while. But there are no perfect answers.

For example, someone says I can use:

```
function isUpperCase(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase();
}
```

This works for a simple case, but not for complicated ones.

For instance:

```
isUpperCase('ABC'); // works good
isUpperCase('ABcd'); // works good too
isUpperCase('汉字'); // not working, should be false.
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
function isUpperCase(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase() && str !== str.toLowerCase();
}
```

to match the last one

Comment: no go mate. `isUpperCase(''.toUpperCase())` returns false

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai On the contrary, I believe: what the OP wants is that `isUpperCase` returns true when the string contains 1) characters that can change case and 2) those characters are in upper case. Your "character" cannot change case, hence the false

Comment: I do not see it. I see a question of "Is this string all UPPERCASE". In which case, it isn't as the numerical values of the characters do not change when converted to upper/lower case.

Comment: Your emoji example is exactly like the OP chinese characters example, and the OP expects `false`

Answer (score 5):

`RegExp` `/^[A-Z]+$/` returns expected result

```js
const isUpperCase = str => /^[A-Z]+$/.test(str);

console.log(
  isUpperCase("ABC")
  , isUpperCase("ABcd")
  , isUpperCase("汉字")
);
```

Comment: mmhhh Should `ABC0123` return `true` ? (it is not exactly clear what the OP wants - see my comment to a comment under my answer)

Comment: @BrunoGrieder `"ABC0123"` does not appear at text of original Question

Answer (score 2):

You can try regex approach.

```
   const isUpperCase2 = (string) => /^[A-Z]*$/.test(string);
   isUpperCase2('ABC'); // true
   isUpperCase2('ABcd'); // false
   isUpperCase2('汉字'); // false
```

Hope this help;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function isUpperCase(str){
   for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
    var charCode=str.charCodeAt(i);
         if(charCode<65||charCode>90){
            return false;
          }
      }
     return true;
   }
```

You can check the letters by ascii code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code seems to be working just fine.

Lower case characters for `汉字` and upper case characters for `汉字` have the same numeric value, as seen here:

```js
var str = '汉字';
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    console.log(str[i], str.charCodeAt(i), str.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i),str.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i))
}
```

let's compare this result with some other string:

```js
    var str = 'łóÐŻCakf8';
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        console.log(str[i], str.charCodeAt(i), str.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(i),str.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i))
    }
```